How to check RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} only contains certain characters?
Say I have an htaccess:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /folder/file.php?fldr=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

This works fine, and redirects anything that reaches this level of the htaccess file.
Now, I want to add a qualifier that this should only run if the %{REQUEST_URI} is only a-z or 0-9 latin characters.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#condition here should only match true if 
# URI contains only any a-z 0-9 characters 1+ times
# And starts with a /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9]+) 
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /folder/file.php?fldr=$1 [NC,L,QSA] 

But I can't find any guidance how to do this. Any suggestions?

That condition does what you suppose in the comment above. So the question is: what is your actual question? And why would you want to more or less double what you already test with the matching pattern in the rule itself? This ready like a classical A/B problem. I suggest you say what you actually want to achieve instead of what you thing what might achieve what you actually want to achieve ...

And just a hint: it is unclear what the pattern [a-z0-9^/]+ is meant to express. You cannot mix positiv and negative patterns. So the ^/ says that you also want to access that accent and a forward slash in your pattern, not that you want to reject such slashes. So I wonder if that pattern really does what you intend, since matching that circumflex accent certainly won't orrur in requested URLs.

@arkascha I want to redirec/rewrite a URL that has domain.com/alphanumeric but not rewrite a URL that has domain.com/alphanumeric_other/folder/etc.html . I understood that the ^ was the indicator for the start of the URL string, so indicating that the REQUEST_URI would always begin with /. But this is a secondary issue to the main one I've described at the start of this comment. Thanks.

In my second comment I referred to the second circumflex accent in that pattern.

@arkascha got you. That was a left over from the original code . I've fixed the typo. :)

The matching pattern you use in the RewriteRule already matches only paths that contain only alphanumeric characters, you just need to anchor that to the end of the matching subject. So something simple like ^([a-z0-9]+)$, maybe ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$. Why shouldn't that be enough?
